# In the Flutter list view , is there a way to know the number of the list item that the user is tapping?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, listitem

In the Flutter list view, is there a way to know the number of the list item that the user is tapping?.

ListTile(
title: Text(snapshot.data[index].quection)
);

Comment: Why don't you use ListView.builder ?

Comment: yes i'm using listView Builder

Comment: Check my answer and mark as answer if it works for you.

Comment: it's works. Thank u

Comment: Pleased to help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `index` of your **ListView.builder** like below

```
            ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print(index);
                  },
                  child: Text("$index")))
```